# sequence of an identity field out of sync in oracle bd

Tags: oracle12c

When i create a table with pk field as identity and i run a script with test rows of data the sequence is out of sync
ex:

```
ID NUMBER(11) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY, CONSTRAINT test_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(ID),
text VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'asd');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,'asd');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(3,'asd');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(4,'asd');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(5,'asd');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(6,'asd');
```

then when i do

```
SELECT "autogenerated sequence".nextval FROM DUAL;
```

the result is 1

is there a way to sync all sequences? 
for the moment ill have to change the pk fields of my test script to NULL, so the sequence is not out of sync

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to sync the sequence with existing data:

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY id
GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH LIMIT VALUE);
```

The START WITH LIMIT VALUE clause will set the sequence to the highest value of the existing data in the column, plus one.